# i cannot see movie playing in iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayer

i have created a application that plays movie on button click..my application is running without any warning or error. But i am not able to see the movie don't know why? 
I have added the Media player framework and also imported the #import in viewController.h 
my button action code is as follow...
-(IBAction)playMyMovie:(id)sender{

```
NSBundle *bundle =[NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"jumps" ofType:@"mov"];
NSURL *movieURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath] retain];
MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
[theMovie play];
```

}

Please tell me what i am missing..

Answer (score 2):

in iPhone simulator you could not play movie properly.

test the applcation on iPhone (Real instrument).

It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a MPMoviePlayerController. It has a `view` property - that is its view. It is your job to put that view into your interface. If you don't, you won't see anything.

Answer (score 0):

try add this line before the [theMovie play]

```
[self.view addSubview:theMovie.view];
```

and also remember to setFullScreen:

```
[self.theMovie setFullscreen:YES];
```

if you dont want fullscreen but want to embed into the view, you can ignore the "setFullscreen", but set the frame for the MPMoviePlayerController view:

```
[self.theMovie.view setFrame:CGRectMake("add in the size you want here")];
```